# Important Event Participants on CiviCRM 4.6.5 no longer supports external ID?

Tags: civievent, import, 4.6

We've been importing event participation in 4.4.6 using their external ID (External Identifier). This appears to be no longer supported in 4.6.5.

Any way to get this to function again?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: UPDATING events requires Internal ID, but skipping duplicate entries allows for the External ID. (Who knows why!)